# Scrapy response.css - two tags without distinct identifiers

Tags: css, python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I am just a beginner in scrapy facing some problems:

```
<tr>
<td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
1.&nbsp;c4<br>

<script type="text/javascript">
...
<\script>

</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">The English Defense, here I give up the centre to Black as a target for attack.</td>
</tr>
```

If I want to get both the `"c4"` text and `"The English Defense, here I give up the centre to Black as a target for attack."`, it would be possible to use `response.css('tr td::text').extract()`.

But what can I do if I want just the second `<td>` tag's text, since the `<td>` tags doesn't have `id` or `class` or anything else? [In this link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), I didn't find a solution to use `style` or `rowspan`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the nth-child selector. In your specific case that would be:
`response.css("td:nth-child(2)::text").extract()`

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know this syntax. Alternatively, I found that xpath could be an option too! Something like `response.xpath('//tr/td[1]/text()').extract()`